# Qt Download Files from QThread Based On Qt Example Doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt, download, qthread

Hi i build simple example striped all irrelevant code and only the problematic code remains
in general i have application that execute thread and inside this thread worker ,   i placed download code that supposed to download more then 30 files , this based on the Download Example Qt gives , the problem is that the QNetworkAccessManager Slot never invokes .
can you please tell me what im doing wrong here ?

```
class MainWindowContainer : public QMainWindow 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindowContainer(QWidget *parent = 0);


 public slots:
    void InvokeDownloadThread();

 private:
    QPushButton *pushButtonInvokeThread;
    PhotosDownloadWorker* pm_hotosDownloadWorker;
  };

#include <QtGui>
#include "MainWindowContainer.h"

MainWindowContainer::MainWindowContainer(QWidget* parent) : 
                                    QMainWindow(parent) 
{
    pushButtonInvokeThread  = new QPushButton(this); 
    QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(pushButtonInvokeThread);
    setLayout(layout);
    QObject::connect(pushButtonInvokeThread,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(InvokeDownloadThread()));

}
void MainWindowContainer::InvokeDownloadThread()
{
     pm_hotosDownloadWorker = new PhotosDownloadWorker(this);
     pm_hotosDownloadWorker->Execute();
}

class PhotosDownloadWorker : public QThread 
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public :
    PhotosDownloadWorker(QObject *parent);
    ~PhotosDownloadWorker();
    void  Execute();
    void append(const QStringList &urlList);
    bool saveToDisk(const QString &filename, QIODevice *data);
    QString saveFileName(const QUrl &url);

 protected:
    void run();

private:
    bool m_abort;
     QList<QNetworkReply *> currentDownloads;
     QFile output;
     QNetworkAccessManager* networkMgr ;  

  public slots:
     void downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply);
     void startNextDownload(const QUrl &url);



};

#include "PhotosDownloadWorker.h"
PhotosDownloadWorker::PhotosDownloadWorker(QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{
    m_abort = false;
    networkMgr = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(networkMgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
 }

 PhotosDownloadWorker::~PhotosDownloadWorker()
{
   m_abort = true; 
    wait();
}

void PhotosDownloadWorker::Execute()
{
    m_abort = false;
    start();
}
void PhotosDownloadWorker::run()
{
    QStringList m_urlList;

    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
    m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");

    // x 30 
    append(m_urlList);
}


void PhotosDownloadWorker::append(const QStringList &urlList)
{
    foreach (QString url, urlList)
    {
         startNextDownload(QUrl::fromEncoded(url.toLocal8Bit()));
    }
 }

void PhotosDownloadWorker::startNextDownload(const QUrl &url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = networkMgr->get(request);
    currentDownloads.append(reply);
}
 bool PhotosDownloadWorker::saveToDisk(const QString &filename, QIODevice *data)
{
    QFile file(filename);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s for writing: %s\n",
                qPrintable(filename),
                qPrintable(file.errorString()));
        return false;
    }

    file.write(data->readAll());
    file.close();

    return true;
}

void PhotosDownloadWorker::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QUrl url = reply->url();
    if (reply->error()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Download of %s failed: %s\n",
                url.toEncoded().constData(),
                qPrintable(reply->errorString()));
    } else {
        QString filename = saveFileName(url);
        if (saveToDisk(filename, reply))
            printf("Download of %s succeeded (saved to %s)\n",
                   url.toEncoded().constData(), qPrintable(filename));
    }

     reply->deleteLater();
     currentDownloads.removeAll(reply);
     if (currentDownloads.isEmpty())
     {

         this->exit();
     }

}
 QString PhotosDownloadWorker::saveFileName(const QUrl &url)
{
    QString path = url.path();
    QString basename = QFileInfo(path).fileName();

    if (basename.isEmpty())
        basename = "download";

    if (QFile::exists(basename)) {
        // already exists, don't overwrite
        int i = 0;
        basename += '.';
        while (QFile::exists(basename + QString::number(i)))
            ++i;

        basename += QString::number(i);
    }

    return basename;
}

//main

#include "MainWindowContainer.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {

     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     MainWindowContainer mainWindowContainer;
     mainWindowContainer.show();
     return app.exec();
 }
```

Comment: What example did you use? Can you point us to an online link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite you call "networkMgr->get(request)" in your code, your thread probably exits before the actual download starts. Try to put "exec()" call at the very bottom of your "QThread::run()" method to enter the event loop in your thread that QNetworkAccessManager requires to be able to work. Also that would prevent the thread from finishing its execution too early. Your code would look like this:

```
void PhotosDownloadWorker::run()
{
  QStringList m_urlList;

  m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");
  m_urlList.append("http://....xxxx......jpg");    
  // x 30 
  append(m_urlList);

  exec();
}
```

Comment: yes its the answer , thanks last question .. how can i terminate thread what is the best way after exec() invoked?

Comment: You can use QThread::quit() or QThread::exit(). With the last one you can pass a result code to return from your QThread::exec() call. Normally I use QThread::quit(). So you can even connect a your final download finished() signal to QThread::quit() slot.

Comment: can you give example i didn't understood

Comment: when i put this->quit in the currentDownloads.isEmpty() its never gets there .

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you explain ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it wouldn't even connect the signal to the slot if the parameter lists are mismatched. See the debugger output for a warning about that at runtime (application output tab).

So, instead of

```
connect(networkMgr, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

do

```
connect(networkMgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

Handling errors is done via QNetworkReply's [`error` signal](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qnetworkreply.html#error-2). Right after you `get` you can connect to the signal.